# how to declare a struct at a specific address?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-memory

I have 2 applications that are using a shared memory segment to pass data from a writing process to a reading process. At the top of the shared memory segment, I want to declare a single header struct to contain general segment data such as buffer count values, read/write offsets, pthread mutex/condition variables, etc. The header struct does NOT contain any pointers. Then the rest of the segment is used for the actual data being passed between the 2 processes.

Since the shared memory segment is attached to the process, I am assured that the segment is indeed valid/accessible to the process. It is easy to simply cast the base segment pointer to a pointer of the header struct type and that works very well for regular data types (like ints, etc) but does not work for the non-integral data types in the struct like pthread mutex/condition variables since they have not actually been declared and allocated.

So, how do I declare and allocate my header struct to start at the specific address of my already allocated shared memory segment?

The following does not appear to work:

```
SmHeader header = *((SmHeader *)m_pBaseAddress);

m_pHeader = &header;
```

where SmHeader is a typedef of my header struct and m_pBaseAddress is the base address of the attached shared memory segment.

thanks,
-Andres

Comment: Show more code, including the declaration of your `m_pHeader` (and perhaps the `class` containing it). Perhaps you might declare `smHeader &header= *(ShHeader*)m_pBaseAddress;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it doesn't work because of the way you're creating it:

```
// this creates a copy of the SmHeader struct, on the stack
SmHeader header = *((SmHeader *)m_pBaseAddress);

// this sets m_pHeader to address of the local variable, not
// m_pBaseAddress
m_pHeader = &header;
```

Try this instead:

```
m_pHeader = (SmHeader *) m_pBaseAddress;
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys. Your suggestion is exactly what I had but does not seem to work because it does not declare nor allocate the header struct. This is fine for ints, chars, etc in the struct, but the pthread variables do not get allocated by just defining the pointer.

Comment: @AndresGonzalez I don't know what you mean by "allocated." The memory is already allocated because it's part of the shared memory segment. And you are "declaring" a pointer to it. What *specifically* is going wrong with the "pthread variables" (and what kind of variables are they)?

Comment: does your first statement actually create the struct on the stack?

Comment: @AndresGonzalez Which statement? *Your* first statement does. The inner cast (of the shared memory address to a `SmHeader *`) tells the compiler "look at this memory and view its contents as a `SmHeader` struct." You then use `*` to *dereference* that pointer and to copy its contents to a newly created `header` variable, which is a local stack variable of type `SmHeader`. And this is certainly not what you want.

Comment: The issue is that the pthread mutex is not working correctly. I originally used your same reasoning, thinking the actually space for the pthread objs was obviously allocated, so it would be fine. But since the mutex is not working (it is process-shared correctly) I thought I must not be allocating the complete struct correctly.

Comment: I now see your point--thanks for clarifying that for me. That indeed is not what I want.  I seem to remember somewhere seeing a way to declare a struct at a specified address but I cannot remember the syntax. That is what "I think" I need.

Comment: @AndresGonzalez When you create the mutex, are you [specifying that it is to be shared across processes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_mutexattr_setpshared.html)? If not, you won't be able to do anything with it outside the process that created it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49979/discussion-between-dvnrrs-and-andres-gonzalez)